# Iterating over a dictonary to find value from a key, value pair

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop that matches user entered input to a key from defined dictionary and returns the corresponding value as an output. However, when the user inputs something that is not in keys, the program prints None and it terminates. But I want the program to continue to let the user enter an input until it finds a match on one of the keys, and it should terminate only when user has provided an input key that is in present the dictionary. I am new to Python so am not sure how to use while statement to loop the process. Appreciate any help.

```
list_dict = {"James" : "Pen Set", "Tim" : "Geometry Box", "Rocky" : "Sticky Notes" , "Jeff" : "Alarm Clock" , "Sandy" : "Highlighters"}
_name = input("Enter Name: ")
x = list_dict.get(_name)
while x == None:
  _name = input("Re-Enter Name: ")
  x = list_dict.get(_name)
  break
else:
  print(_name, "got", x)
break
```

Comment: Remove the ``break``.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `break` keyword directly inside a while-loop without any condition. The result is that the loop content can only run once before exiting the loop. If you wish to keep the loop running, remove the `break` keyword.

Here is a sample answer to your question:

```py
list_dict = {"James" : "Pen Set", "Tim" : "Geometry Box", "Rocky" : "Sticky Notes" , "Jeff" : "Alarm Clock" , "Sandy" : "Highlighters"}

# first input
_name = input("Enter Name: ")
# obtain x
x = list_dict.get(_name)

# perform checking on the latest value of x
while x == None:
  _name = input("Re-Enter Name: ")
  x = list_dict.get(_name)
  # if x is a valid value, the while statement above will detect this and terminate the loop

# final output
print(_name, "got", x)
```

Remark 1: keep in mind that loops can be terminated automatically by setting the loop condition correctly. Arbitrary use of `break` and `continue` keywords is generally advised against due to its disruption to normal programme flow.

Remark 2: using `else` keyword with `while` keyword on the same level means that the `else` block is only executed if the while-loop completes its execution without any interruptions, i.e. never encountering the `break` keyword. This is inapplicable to your case, since the termination condition is simple, and there is no need to detect if the while-loop is interrupted.

Comment: In Python [loops may have an ``else`` clause](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-try-stmt).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know this as well, just checked out the documentation, quite a handy feature to use.
This feature is too advanced to be applicable in this case though.

Comment: Edited my answer to include @MisterMiyagi 's correction

Answer (score 0):

The provided code only requires a minor change to produce the behavior that you expect. In the following modified code, both `break` statements have been removed:

```python
list_dict = {"James" : "Pen Set", "Tim" : "Geometry Box", "Rocky" : "Sticky Notes" , "Jeff" : "Alarm Clock" , "Sandy" : "Highlighters"}
_name = input("Enter Name: ")
x = list_dict.get(_name)
while x == None:
  _name = input("Re-Enter Name: ")
  x = list_dict.get(_name)
  # break
else:
  print(_name, "got", x)
# break
```

**Explanation**

- Remove the first `break` to prevent the `while` loop from always exiting after the first iteration. If the user-provided name does not exist in `list_dict`, we want the `while` loop to continue iterating. By placing a `break`, we are forcing the `while` loop to exit after the first iteration. It's also important to note that a `break` causes an `else` clause to be skipped. With the original code, if the first name entered does not exist, but the second name entered does exist, the `break` causes the `else` clause to be skipped and the `print` statement is not executed.
- Remove the second `break` because it is only applicable when placed inside a loop.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) for the `break` statement for additional information.

**Testing the modified code**

```
Enter Name: TestName1
Re-Enter Name: TestName2
Re-Enter Name: Jeff
Jeff got Alarm Clock
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the break statement. If you remove it, the program should work fine ;)

Answer (score -1):

I improved a little of your code and i think this help to solve your problem.

```
list_dict = {"James" : "Pen Set", "Tim" : "Geometry Box", "Rocky" : 
"Sticky Notes" , "Jeff" : "Alarm Clock" , "Sandy" : "Highlighters"}
_name = input("Enter Name: ")

while _name not in list_dict.keys():
   _name = input("Re-Enter Name: ")
print(f'{_name} got {list_dict.get(_name)}')
```

Comment: You could improve this by moving the check from the ``if`` to the ``while``, dropping the ``if``/``else``/``break`` entirely. Note that you can directly check ``_name not in list_dict`` and access the value as ``list_dict[_name]`` if you are sure the key exists.

Comment: Edited my answer to include @MisterMiyagi correction